# How do I use Taxonomy reference field tokens in a path alias?

Tags: path-aliases, tokens

I have a content type with two taxonomy entity reference fields. Both are required fields that only allow one value. I have path_auto and token enabled. I would like to use them to set the path of the node type.

This is the path pattern that is a problem:

`[node:field_main_site_section:entity:name]/[node:field_content_category:entity:name]/[node:title]`

It looks close to the answer given in [another question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/277285/drupal-8-pathauto-taxonomy-terms-in-content-paths)n here.

**Result:** The only thing showing up in the path is the title.

Versions: Drupal 8.8.5, pathauto 1.8, token 1.7

**What have I tried?**

I tried running the code through the debugger and found out that the action is in the functions `PathautoGenerator::createEntityAlias()` and `Token::generate()`. I see that the three tokens are found and that a Node data is passed to Token generate. Then the `generate` function runs `$replacements = $this->moduleHandler->invokeAll('tokens', [$type, $tokens, $data, $options, $bubbleable_metadata])`. There were 9 modules found that implement hook_tokens but the only one returning any data is node_tokens. Looking at that code I don't see any attempt to return fields.

I also found [an issue on the token module](https://www.drupal.org/project/token/issues/2430821) that indicated that I might be missing Token view modes. I was indeed missing a token view mode for my two taxonomy vocabularies so I created them. I added each field in the vocabulary including "name" in plain text.

I also tried to guess that the node needed to be converted to an entity to grab it's fields:

`[node:entity:field_main_site_section:entity:name]/[node:entity:field_content_category:entity:name]/[node:title]`

That was an invalid pattern.

**Question:**
What is the correct pattern or what else do I need to configure?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by two changes:

- Apply the patch from [this Token issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/token/issues/3088219), "Inconsistent loading of third party hook implementations"
- Make sure Token display mode exists for each taxonomy vocabulary

I tested and confirmed that both the patch and the display mode config changes were needed.